# mysqldump.exe from Java program

Tags: windows

Im trying to dump a mysql database using Java. I have followed the examples found on Stack Overflow and am currently using the below code to call the mysqldump.exe.

String executeCmd = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\mysqldump.exe -u" + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + "  --databases " + dbName + " >" + savePath;

System.out.println("executing ->  " + executeCmd);

Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);

When I run it in Eclipse it prints the string and does nothing else. When I paste the string into a normal command prompt it tells me access denied. When I paste the string into a command prompt with admin privilege's it works correctly. I dont understand why noone else is having this issue lol. I googled forever and cant seem to find anyone else having the same issue. Can someone pleases help with this?

Comment: Make sure you do not need elevated privileges to access the given path.

Comment: Got it. You were correct Shadow. Thank you. I just moved the sqldump.exe to a different directory and it works now.